# Why aliased function makes performance down in the case in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

> [For Clarify my question]: **I want to know why shorthanded code let performance down when I using the *State Monad*.**
>   This question is not for optimizing my code. 
>   This code is for benchmarking of the stateful monads.
>   You can see the `State`-free pure version and `ST` monad version code and benchmark result from [the master branch of my repo](https://github.com/QuietJoon/StatefulMonadBench).

When I try to shorthand in my code, I've got an unexpected result by the shorthanded function. (Please refer [focused benchmark](https://gerundiveborder.htmlpasta.com/) and [overall benchmark](https://unpassionedtiffany.htmlpasta.com)

In [LazinessTest branch of this repository](https://github.com/QuietJoon/StatefulMonadBench/blob/LazinessTest/src/SingleState/StrictState.hs#L60),

I tried to shorthand [this code](https://github.com/QuietJoon/StatefulMonadBench/blob/LazinessTest/src/SingleState/StrictState.hs#L60),

```hs
runTimeSlot' :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> State Data [Int]
runTimeSlot' (target : idx : rest) inst operand = do
  d <- get
  case inst of
    -- this code ↓↓↓↓
    0 -> case (rem target sizeOfTarget) of
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setTime operand d)
      ...
    1 -> case (rem target sizeOfTarget) of
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyTime (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      ...
```

as like as following

```hs
runTimeSlot'' :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> State Data [Int]
runTimeSlot'' (target : idx : rest) inst operand = do
  d <- get
  case inst of
    -- as like as ↓↓↓↓
    0 -> case targetInData of
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setTime operand d)
      ...
    1 -> case targetInData of
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyTime (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      ...
  where targetInData = rem target sizeOfTarget
```

And it shows that drastically performance down from 622 μs to 1.767 ms.

Even the value `targetInData` would be evaluated in just next step `case`, 
I thought that I may figure it by making the `targetInData` strictly like

```hs
runTimeSlot''' :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> State Data [Int]
runTimeSlot''' (target : idx : rest) inst operand = do
  d <- get
  -- evaluate it ↓↓ here before it used
  targetInData `seq` case inst of
    0 -> case targetInData of
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setTime operand d)
      ...
    1 -> case targetInData of
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyTime (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      ...
  where targetInData = rem target sizeOfTarget
```

But this also does not work. (Takes 1.758 ms)

Based on @AndrásKovács 's comment (Thanks, @AndrásKovács)
I've added `BangPatterns` to `targetInData` as like as

```hs
runTimeSlot''b :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> State Data [Int]
runTimeSlot''b (target : idx : rest) inst operand = do
  d <- get
  case inst of
    0 -> case targetInData of -- Set
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setTime operand d)
      ...
    1 -> case targetInData of -- Mod
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyTime (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      ...
  where !targetInData = rem target sizeOfTarget

runTimeSlot'''b :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> State Data [Int]
runTimeSlot'''b (target : idx : rest) inst operand = do
  d <- get
  -- evaluate it ↓↓ here before it used
  targetInData `seq` case inst of
    0 -> case targetInData of
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setTime operand d)
      ...
    1 -> case targetInData of
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyTime (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      ...
  where !targetInData = rem target sizeOfTarget
```

And it helps a little, but it does not solves the unexpected situation completely.

- 1.767 ms @ `runTimeSlot''` -> 1.527 ms @ `runTimeSlot''b`
- 1.758 ms @ `runTimeSlot'''` -> 1.503 ms @ `runTimeSlot'''b`

Why not as like as 622 μs @ `runTimeSlot`???

I couldn't explain this situation with laziness by myself.

Could you explain why just replacing `(rem target sizeOfTaregt)` as shorthand code makes the performance worse?

Here is single compilable example code and [benchmark result](https://gerundiveborder.htmlpasta.com/):
(I'm sorry that I couldn't reduce unnecessary codes enough)

```hs
-- dependencies: base, containers, criterion, deepseq, mtl, splitmix
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}
module Main where


import           Criterion.Main
import           Criterion.Types

import           Control.DeepSeq
import           Control.Monad.State.Strict

import           Data.Bifunctor
import           Data.Maybe
import qualified Data.IntMap                   as IM
import           Data.List

import           System.Random.SplitMix


myConfig60s =
  defaultConfig { timeLimit = 60.0, resamples = 10000, verbosity = Verbose }

randomInts :: SMGen -> [Int]
randomInts = unfoldr (Just . (first fromIntegral . bitmaskWithRejection64 64))

main :: IO ()
main = do
  putStrLn "Initialize"
  let size                             = 10000
  let instSize                         = 2
  let targetSize                       = 16
  let operandSize                      = 256
  let i0Gen                            = (mkSMGen . fromIntegral) 0
  let (targetGen, i1Gen)               = splitSMGen i0Gen
  let (instGen, i2Gen)                 = splitSMGen i1Gen
  let (operGen, iGen)                  = splitSMGen i2Gen
  let infTargetList = map (\x -> rem x targetSize) $ randomInts targetGen
  let infInstList = map (\x -> rem x instSize) $ randomInts instGen
  let infOperandList = map (\x -> rem x operandSize + 1) $ randomInts operGen
  let (iTime : iBalance : iStatus : _) = randomInts iGen
  let targetList                       = take (size * 2) infTargetList
  let instList                         = take size infInstList
  let operandList                      = take size infOperandList

  targetList `deepseq` instList `deepseq` operandList `deepseq` putStrLn
    "Evaluated"

  let iData = Data iTime iBalance iStatus IM.empty

  let
    ssBench =
      bgroup "SingleState Simulation"
        $ [ bench "SingleState.StrictPure'" $ nf
            ( runSimulatorPure' size targetList instList operandList
            )
            iData
          , bench "SingleState.StrictPure''" $ nf
            ( runSimulatorPure'' size targetList instList operandList
            )
            iData
          , bench "SingleState.StrictState'" $ nf
            ( runState
            $ runSimulator' size targetList instList operandList
            )
            iData
          , bench "SingleState.StrictState''" $ nf
            ( runState
            $ runSimulator'' size targetList instList operandList
            )
            iData
          , bench "SingleState.StrictState''b" $ nf
            ( runState
            $ runSimulator''b size targetList instList operandList
            )
            iData
          , bench "SingleState.StrictState'''" $ nf
            ( runState
            $ runSimulator''' size targetList instList operandList
            )
            iData
          , bench "SingleState.StrictState'''b" $ nf
            ( runState
            $ runSimulator'''b size targetList instList operandList
            )
            iData
          , bench "SingleState.StrictState''''" $ nf
            ( runState
            $ runSimulator'''' size targetList instList operandList
            )
            iData
          , bench "SingleState.StrictState'''''" $ nf
            ( runState
            $ runSimulator''''' size targetList instList operandList
            )
            iData
          ]
  putStrLn "Do bench"
  defaultMainWith myConfig60s [ssBench]


-- from SingleState.StrictPure of the repo
runSimulatorPure' :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> Data -> Data
runSimulatorPure' 0 _ _ _ d = d
runSimulatorPure' size tList (i : iList) (o : oList) d =
  restTList
    `seq` newData
    `seq` runSimulatorPure' (size - 1) restTList iList oList newData
  where (restTList, newData) = runTimeSlotPure' tList i o d

runTimeSlotPure' :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Data -> ([Int], Data)
runTimeSlotPure' (target : idx : rest) inst operand d = case inst of
  0 -> case (rem target sizeOfTarget) of -- Set
    0 -> ((idx : rest), setTime operand d)
    1 -> ((idx : rest), setBalance operand d)
    2 -> ((idx : rest), setStatus operand d)
    3 -> (rest, setEntry idx operand d)
  1 -> case (rem target sizeOfTarget) of -- Mod
    0 -> ((idx : rest), modifyTime (\x -> rem x operand) d)
    1 -> ((idx : rest), modifyBalance (\x -> rem x operand) d)
    2 -> ((idx : rest), modifyStatus (\x -> rem x operand) d)
    3 -> (rest, modifyEntry (\x -> rem x operand) idx d)


runSimulatorPure'' :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> Data -> Data
runSimulatorPure'' 0 _ _ _ d = d
runSimulatorPure'' size tList (i : iList) (o : oList) d =
  restTList
    `seq` newData
    `seq` runSimulatorPure'' (size - 1) restTList iList oList newData
  where (restTList, newData) = runTimeSlotPure'' tList i o d

runTimeSlotPure'' :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> Data -> ([Int], Data)
runTimeSlotPure'' (target : idx : rest) inst operand d = case inst of
  0 -> case targetInData of -- Set
    0 -> ((idx : rest), setTime operand d)
    1 -> ((idx : rest), setBalance operand d)
    2 -> ((idx : rest), setStatus operand d)
    3 -> (rest, setEntry idx operand d)
  1 -> case targetInData of -- Mod
    0 -> ((idx : rest), modifyTime (\x -> rem x operand) d)
    1 -> ((idx : rest), modifyBalance (\x -> rem x operand) d)
    2 -> ((idx : rest), modifyStatus (\x -> rem x operand) d)
    3 -> (rest, modifyEntry (\x -> rem x operand) idx d)
  where targetInData = rem target sizeOfTarget


-- from SingleState.StrictState of the repo
runSimulator :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> State Data Data
runSimulator 0    _     _           _           = get
runSimulator size tList (i : iList) (o : oList) = do
  restTList <- runTimeSlot tList i o
  runSimulator (size - 1) restTList iList oList

runTimeSlot :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> State Data [Int]
runTimeSlot (target : idx : rest) inst operand = do
  d <- get
  case inst of
    0 -> case (rem target sizeOfTarget) of -- Set
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setTime operand d)
      1 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setBalance operand d)
      2 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setStatus operand d)
      3 -> state $ \s -> (rest, setEntry idx operand d)
    1 -> case (rem target sizeOfTarget) of -- Mod
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyTime rF d)
      1 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyBalance rF d)
      2 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyStatus rF d)
      3 -> state $ \s -> (rest, modifyEntry rF idx d)
    -- 2 -> Add
    -- 3 -> Div
  where rF x = rem x operand


runSimulator' :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> State Data Data
runSimulator' 0    _     _           _           = get
runSimulator' size tList (i : iList) (o : oList) = do
  restTList <- runTimeSlot' tList i o
  runSimulator' (size - 1) restTList iList oList

runTimeSlot' :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> State Data [Int]
runTimeSlot' (target : idx : rest) inst operand = do
  d <- get
  case inst of
    0 -> case (rem target sizeOfTarget) of -- Set
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setTime operand d)
      1 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setBalance operand d)
      2 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setStatus operand d)
      3 -> state $ \s -> (rest, setEntry idx operand d)
    1 -> case (rem target sizeOfTarget) of -- Mod
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyTime (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      1 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyBalance (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      2 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyStatus (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      3 -> state $ \s -> (rest, modifyEntry (\x -> rem x operand) idx d)
    -- 2 -> Add
    -- 3 -> Div


runSimulator'' :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> State Data Data
runSimulator'' 0    _     _           _           = get
runSimulator'' size tList (i : iList) (o : oList) = do
  restTList <- runTimeSlot'' tList i o
  runSimulator'' (size - 1) restTList iList oList

runTimeSlot'' :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> State Data [Int]
runTimeSlot'' (target : idx : rest) inst operand = do
  d <- get
  case inst of
    0 -> case targetInData of -- Set
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setTime operand d)
      1 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setBalance operand d)
      2 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setStatus operand d)
      3 -> state $ \s -> (rest, setEntry idx operand d)
    1 -> case targetInData of -- Mod
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyTime (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      1 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyBalance (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      2 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyStatus (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      3 -> state $ \s -> (rest, modifyEntry (\x -> rem x operand) idx d)
    -- 2 -> Add
    -- 3 -> Div
  where targetInData = rem target sizeOfTarget


runSimulator''b :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> State Data Data
runSimulator''b 0    _     _           _           = get
runSimulator''b size tList (i : iList) (o : oList) = do
  restTList <- runTimeSlot''b tList i o
  runSimulator''b (size - 1) restTList iList oList

runTimeSlot''b :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> State Data [Int]
runTimeSlot''b (target : idx : rest) inst operand = do
  d <- get
  case inst of
    0 -> case targetInData of -- Set
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setTime operand d)
      1 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setBalance operand d)
      2 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setStatus operand d)
      3 -> state $ \s -> (rest, setEntry idx operand d)
    1 -> case targetInData of -- Mod
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyTime (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      1 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyBalance (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      2 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyStatus (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      3 -> state $ \s -> (rest, modifyEntry (\x -> rem x operand) idx d)
    -- 2 -> Add
    -- 3 -> Div
  where !targetInData = rem target sizeOfTarget


runSimulator''' :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> State Data Data
runSimulator''' 0    _     _           _           = get
runSimulator''' size tList (i : iList) (o : oList) = do
  restTList <- runTimeSlot''' tList i o
  runSimulator''' (size - 1) restTList iList oList

runTimeSlot''' :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> State Data [Int]
runTimeSlot''' (target : idx : rest) inst operand = do
  d <- get
  targetInData `seq` case inst of
    0 -> case targetInData of -- Set
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setTime operand d)
      1 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setBalance operand d)
      2 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setStatus operand d)
      3 -> state $ \s -> (rest, setEntry idx operand d)
    1 -> case targetInData of -- Mod
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyTime (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      1 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyBalance (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      2 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyStatus (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      3 -> state $ \s -> (rest, modifyEntry (\x -> rem x operand) idx d)
    -- 2 -> Add
    -- 3 -> Div
  where targetInData = rem target sizeOfTarget


runSimulator'''b :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> State Data Data
runSimulator'''b 0    _     _           _           = get
runSimulator'''b size tList (i : iList) (o : oList) = do
  restTList <- runTimeSlot'''b tList i o
  runSimulator'''b (size - 1) restTList iList oList

runTimeSlot'''b :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> State Data [Int]
runTimeSlot'''b (target : idx : rest) inst operand = do
  d <- get
  targetInData `seq` case inst of
    0 -> case targetInData of -- Set
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setTime operand d)
      1 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setBalance operand d)
      2 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setStatus operand d)
      3 -> state $ \s -> (rest, setEntry idx operand d)
    1 -> case targetInData of -- Mod
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyTime (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      1 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyBalance (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      2 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyStatus (\x -> rem x operand) d)
      3 -> state $ \s -> (rest, modifyEntry (\x -> rem x operand) idx d)
    -- 2 -> Add
    -- 3 -> Div
  where !targetInData = rem target sizeOfTarget


runSimulator'''' :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> State Data Data
runSimulator'''' 0    _     _           _           = get
runSimulator'''' size tList (i : iList) (o : oList) = do
  restTList <- runTimeSlot'''' tList i o
  runSimulator'''' (size - 1) restTList iList oList

runTimeSlot'''' :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> State Data [Int]
runTimeSlot'''' (target : idx : rest) inst operand = do
  d <- get
  case inst of
    0 -> case targetInData of -- Set
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setTime operand d)
      1 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setBalance operand d)
      2 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setStatus operand d)
      3 -> state $ \s -> (rest, setEntry idx operand d)
    1 -> case targetInData of -- Mod
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyTime rF d)
      1 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyBalance rF d)
      2 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyStatus rF d)
      3 -> state $ \s -> (rest, modifyEntry rF idx d)
    -- 2 -> Add
    -- 3 -> Div
  where
    targetInData = rem target sizeOfTarget
    rF x = rem x operand


runSimulator''''' :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> State Data Data
runSimulator''''' 0    _     _           _           = get
runSimulator''''' size tList (i : iList) (o : oList) = do
  restTList <- runTimeSlot''''' tList i o
  runSimulator''''' (size - 1) restTList iList oList

runTimeSlot''''' :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> State Data [Int]
runTimeSlot''''' (target : idx : rest) inst operand = do
  d <- get
  targetInData `seq` case inst of
    0 -> case targetInData of -- Set
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setTime operand d)
      1 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setBalance operand d)
      2 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setStatus operand d)
      3 -> state $ \s -> (rest, setEntry idx operand d)
    1 -> case targetInData of -- Mod
      0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyTime rF d)
      1 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyBalance rF d)
      2 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), modifyStatus rF d)
      3 -> state $ \s -> (rest, modifyEntry rF idx d)
    -- 2 -> Add
    -- 3 -> Div
  where
    targetInData = rem target sizeOfTarget
    rF x = rem x operand

type Balance = Int
type Time = Int
type Status = Int
type Idx = Int
type Datum = Int

data Data = Data
  { time :: Time
  , balance :: Balance
  , status :: Status
  , aMap :: IM.IntMap Datum
  } deriving (Show,Eq)

sizeOfTarget :: Int
sizeOfTarget = 4

instance NFData Data where
  rnf (Data t b s m) = rnf t `seq` rnf b `seq` rnf s `seq` rnf m

getTime    = time
getBalance = balance
getStatus  = status
getEntry idx = fromMaybe 0 . IM.lookup idx . aMap
setTime newTime d = d { time = newTime }
setBalance newBalance d = d { balance = newBalance }
setStatus newStatus d = d { status = newStatus }
setEntry idx aDatum d = d { aMap = IM.insert idx aDatum (aMap d) }
modifyTime f d = d { time = f (time d) }
modifyBalance f d = d { balance = f (balance d) }
modifyStatus f d = d { status = f (status d) }
modifyEntry f idx d = d { aMap = IM.adjust f idx (aMap d) }
```

**Updated**

- Based on [@AndrásKovács 's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61917443/why-aliased-function-makes-performance-down-in-the-case-in-haskell?noredirect=1#comment109522591_61917443), I've add new test functions.
- Updated every measured time with the new functions.
- Please refer `State`-free version and `ST` monad version from [the master branch](https://github.com/QuietJoon/StatefulMonadBench)

**P.S.**

- I've run this code with [GHC options without `-threaded` and with `-O2`](https://github.com/QuietJoon/StatefulMonadBench/blob/LazinessTest/package.yaml).
- You can see the entire result of the benchmark in [here](https://gerundiveborder.htmlpasta.com/) and [here](https://github.com/QuietJoon/StatefulMonadBench/blob/LazinessTest/Results/Laziness/ResultOnWorkStation.BangPatterns.html).
- Pure function without State monad version does not show any performance change by this shorthanded code.
- You can build the entire benchmark about this problem from [this code](https://github.com/QuietJoon/StatefulMonadBench/blob/LazinessTest/benchmarks/laziness/Main.hs).

Comment: It'd be helpful to post here an example which compiles as it is, so we don't have to download your repo. Also, `-O3` does not exist in GHC, the maximum is `-O2`. Regarding performance, I would try `where !targetInData = ...` as a first step.

Comment: @AndrásKovács Yes, I have to provide single compilable example code. But because it depends on a package which are not uploaded on Hackage in current, I couldn't provide single example code yet. I'll write it ASAP.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I see from looking at Core output via `ghc -O2 -ddump-simpl -dsuppress-all`, GHC simply misses `State` tuple unboxing and worker-wrapping if we do the following:

```
runTimeSlot2 :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> State Data [Int]
runTimeSlot2 (target : idx : rest) inst operand = do
  d <- get
  case inst of
    0 -> ...
    1 -> ..
    where targetInData = rem target sizeOfTarget
```

But it works in the following case. We can also put `targetInData` in a `let` before the `case`.

```
runTimeSlot2 :: [Int] -> Int -> Int -> State Data [Int]
runTimeSlot2 (target : idx : rest) inst operand = do
  d <- get
  case inst of
    0 -> ...
    1 -> ..
  where targetInData = rem target sizeOfTarget
```

What's the reason? I have no idea. But this is an example where we are placing a bit too much trust in GHC anyway, and the program is far from optimal to begin with. First, I'd make `Data` strict, and use `whnf` in the benchmark instead of `nf`:

```
data Data = Data
  { time :: !Time
  , balance :: !Balance
  , status :: !Status
  , aMap :: !(IM.IntMap Datum)
  } deriving (Show,Eq)
```

Second, I don't think the `State` buys us much in this particular example, and we can just write a tail-recursive function:

```
runSimulator1 :: Int -> [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> Data -> Data
runSimulator1 = go where
  go 0 _ _ _ d = d
  go size (target : (idx : rest)) (i : iList) (o : oList) d =
    let targetInData = rem target sizeOfTarget in
    case i of
      0 -> case targetInData of
        0 -> go (size - 1) (idx : rest) iList oList (setTime o d)
        1 -> go (size - 1) (idx : rest) iList oList (setBalance o d)
        2 -> go (size - 1) (idx : rest) iList oList (setStatus o d)
        3 -> go (size - 1) rest         iList oList (setEntry idx o d)
      1 -> case targetInData of
        0 -> go (size - 1) (idx : rest) iList oList (modifyTime    (\x -> rem x o) d)
        1 -> go (size - 1) (idx : rest) iList oList (modifyBalance (\x -> rem x o) d)
        2 -> go (size - 1) (idx : rest) iList oList (modifyStatus  (\x -> rem x o) d)
        3 -> go (size - 1) rest         iList oList (modifyEntry   (\x -> rem x o) idx d)
```

This runs a bit more than twice as fast on my computer than the better performing variant in your original benchmark.

I note a performance issue in the original code:

```
...
0 -> case targetInData of
  0 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setTime operand d)
  1 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setBalance operand d)
  2 -> state $ \s -> ((idx : rest), setStatus operand d)
  3 -> state $ \s -> (rest, setEntry idx operand d)
...
```

Above, all the returned state like `setTime operand d` is lazy. Hence, we get a large number of thunks. We can do instead:

```
0 -> case targetInData of -- Set
  0 -> (idx : rest) <$ (put $! setTime operand d)
  1 -> (idx : rest) <$ (put $! setBalance operand d)
  2 -> (idx : rest) <$ (put $! setStatus operand d)
  3 ->  rest        <$ (put $! setEntry idx operand d)
```

This gives us a performance boost, but it still a bit slower than my `State`-free version, because GHC can unbox `Data` as a plain function argument or result, but it cannot unbox `Data` inside the `State` tuple.

In general, if you really want to optimize, the most robust solution is pure (non-monadic) and strict plain functions, preferably tail-recursive. It depends on the development situation whether it's worth the effort to optimize to such degree.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  However, what I want to know is why the performance is down with shorthanded code when I using State monad.
I already have State-free version to compare many stateful monad and pure implementation(you can see the code and benchmark result in my repo of master branch: https://github.com/QuietJoon/StatefulMonadBench/blob/master/src/SingleState/StrictPure.hs), and I know that State-free version has no issue.  (Sorry for not mention about this...)

Comment: It's a GHC optimization failure caused by some internal detail. I doubt that it's worth to investigate, I believe it's better to just stick to defensive programming in performance-critical code, and not leave a lot up to the whims of the optimizer.

Comment: I'm interested as well in what the actual mechanism of failure is, but I think we'll need a GHC dev or expert for that.